# Load 2nd web page in background to get content from this web page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I couldn't find anything about this topic, maybe because I'm not a good english speaker and can't find the right words to search for in google therefore.

I'm currently working on an Chrome browser extension which enables me to search for user accounts on a specified web page by using the context menu. Example: If I select the text `name123` on any webpage and click the context menu entry, a new tab `http://www.webpage.de/user/name123/` is opened.

Now I want to extend the extensions capabilities: I want to search for email addresses, too. For that I can use `http://www.webpage.de/search/name123@mail.com/` which brings up a list of all user with the email address `name123@mail.com`. From there, I could extract the link to the user account as follows:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("xyz")[0].href
```

My question: Can I skip the loading of `http://www.webpage.de/search/name123@mail.com/` and the "extraction" of the url to the user account? Respectively, can I hide the procedure of opening this additional web page? Does JavaScript support any kind of "preloading" of a webpages content, without being displayed in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you can parse the required link from raw HTML, you can fetch the page via an `XMLHttpRequest` in the background page, examine the result and then open the real profile page.

If the page is dynamic and you need its scripts to run before you can extract the link, you can load it in an iframe in the background page and examine it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it.

1. Add permessions to your `manifest.json` file: `'http://www.webpage.de/*'`
2. Create neccesary ajax requests from [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).